# Google Maps Android API v2 blocks UI thread

Tags: android, api, google-maps, android-fragments, performance

Inside FragmentActivity I replace Fragment which has nested TabPageIndicator (2 tabs inside).

First tab - Fragment with Description.
Second tab - Fragment with map inside + markers!

When I start FragmentActivity, pause is nearby 3-8 sec (depends on performance of the phone).

Reason - map rendering.

How can I speed up launching?

---

FragmentStatePagerAdapter

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        return new Fragment1();
    case 1:
        return new Fragment2();
    }
    return null;
}
```

---

Fragment2

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.i(Util.TAG, getClass().getName() + " onCreateView");
    if (view != null) {
        ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
        if (parent != null)
            parent.removeView(view);
    }
    try {
        view = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.map_view, container, false);
    } catch (InflateException e) {

    }
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
    return view;
}

public void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
    if (map == null) {
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        map = mapFragment.getMap();
        if (map != null) {
            setUpMap();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Unable to create map", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}

private void setUpMap() {
    map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(KIEV).title("Kiev").snippet("Ukraine"));// .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher))
    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(KIEV, 15));
    map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10), 2000, null);
    map.setOnMapLoadedCallback(this);
}
```

I tried to comment everything except of this:

```
view = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.map_view, container, false);
```

but result is the same. Map initialization is too long.

Should I use separate thread to load map view? (If yes, how can i get layout inflater and container in background thread)

Also I decide to load map if fragment is visible, but it wasn't a good idea.

Comment: you have to show relevant parts of your code, otherwise nobody can tell you how to improve permormance

Comment: Do you have some code to show how your doing it? When you start the fragment activity are you loading the map on your main ui thread? Putting it in a seperate thread or inside an AsyncTask might help? But I'm just guessing as I can't see any code.

Comment: Use Traceview and determine where your problem actually lies.